# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback", referenced from

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, architecture

I am facing the Below error.
minimum deployment target is 8.0
I am using Xcode 7.3.1

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate loadInitialParameters] in AppDelegate.o
  "_AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate loadInitialParameters] in AppDelegate.o
  "_AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate sessionDidInterrupt:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyGeneralEncapsulatedObject", referenced from:
      -[BiscootAudioPlayer handleTimedMetadata:] in BiscootAudioPlayer.o
  "_AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification", referenced from:
      -[BiscootAudioPlayer stopPlayer] in BiscootAudioPlayer.o
      -[BiscootAudioPlayer dealloc] in BiscootAudioPlayer.o
      -[BiscootAudioPlayer prepareToPlayAsset:withKeys:] in BiscootAudioPlayer.o
      -[BiscootAudioPlayer updateCurrentTimeForPlayer] in BiscootAudioPlayer.o
  "_CATransform3DConcat", referenced from:
      -[CustomIOS7AlertView close] in CustomIOS7AlertView.o
      ___28-[CustomIOS7AlertView close]_block_invoke in CustomIOS7AlertView.o
      ___52+[MMDrawerVisualState slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock]_block_invoke in MMDrawerVisualState.o
      ___51+[MMDrawerVisualState swingingDoorVisualStateBlock]_block_invoke in MMDrawerVisualState.o
  "_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
      ___73-[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:]_block_invoke in MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager.o
      ___52+[MMDrawerVisualState slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock]_block_invoke in MMDrawerVisualState.o
      ___51+[MMDrawerVisualState swingingDoorVisualStateBlock]_block_invoke in MMDrawerVisualState.o
      ___66+[MMDrawerVisualState parallaxVisualStateBlockWithParallaxFactor:]_block_invoke in MMDrawerVisualState.o
      -[MMDrawerController applyOvershootScaleTransformForDrawerSide:percentVisible:] in MMDrawerController.o
      -[MMDrawerController resetDrawerVisualStateForDrawerSide:] in MMDrawerController.o
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[CustomIOS7AlertView close] in CustomIOS7AlertView.o
      ___40-[SVPullToRefreshView rotateArrow:hide:]_block_invoke in UIScrollView+SVPullToRefresh.o
  "_CATransform3DMakeScale", referenced from:
      ___73-[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:]_block_invoke in
```

If any of you friends have faced this issue before kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

add x86_64 in the Valid Architectures in Build Settings and mark the Build Active Architecture Only to NO

Comment: Besides that you need to AVFoundation.framework into Project->Target->linked Frameworks and Libraries list. Probably you need AVKit.framework as well

Answer (score 1):

For CATransform* errors, add QuartzCore in Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases:
[image]